# Living Reviews in Relativity Biblatex style (simplified [DOI], [ADS], [ARXIV] identifiers)

Tags: biblatex

I would like to emulate this style of bibliography present in numerous Living Reviews in Relativity(Springer). Specifically, the Arxiv, DOI and ADS identifier all simplified in square brackets like the picture.  I am familiar with the use of biblatex, but I couldn´t find a way to correctly implement this style.
Currently I have

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,language=english,bibstyle=numeric,backref=true,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
with e.g.
```

```
@ARTICLE{2016PhRvD..94l4038D,
       author = {{De Laurentis}, Mariafelicia and {Porth}, Oliver and {Bovard}, Luke and
         {Ahmedov}, Bobomurat and {Abdujabbarov}, Ahmadjon},
        title = "{Constraining alternative theories of gravity using GW150914 and GW151226}",
      journal = {\prd},
     keywords = {General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology},
         year = "2016",
        month = "Dec",
       volume = {94},
       number = {12},
          eid = {124038},
        pages = {124038},
          doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.94.124038},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1611.05766},
 primaryClass = {gr-qc},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016PhRvD..94l4038D},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

[image: Luc Blanchet, Living Reviews] 
[image: C.M.Will Living Reviews]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code you have tried so far and do not forget to add two used bib entries to your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to redefine the relevant field formats. You can find the defaults in [`biblatex.def`, ll. 445-501 in v3.12](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L445-L501).

The main changes involve adding `\mkbibbrackets` and changing the text argument of `\href`. Note that I removed the `\ifhyperref` test in some formats, which means that the code now requires `hyperref` (and indeed it makes little sense just to print "DOI" if no link can be attached to it, so I think this is an acceptable change).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric-comp, sorting=nyt,
  giveninits=true,
  natbib=true, backref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{%
    \href{https://doi.org/#1}{\mkbibacro{DOI}}}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{%
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{https://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
         arXiv\addcolon
         \nolinkurl{#1}%
         \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
           {}
           {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
      {arXiv\addcolon
       \nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
         {}
         {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:googlebooks}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{%
    \href{http://books.google.com/books?id=#1}{Google Books}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,baez/article,wassenberg,kastenholz,wilde}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "J. C. Baez and A. D. Lauda. ‘Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2-Groups’. Version 3. In: Theory and Applications of Categories 12 (2004), pp. 423–491. [arXiv:math/0307200v3] (cit. on p. 1)." etc. etc.]

Answer (score 0):

from the original livrevrel.bst file:

```
% shows DOI and links doi
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    {"{\small[\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{DOI" * "}]}" *}
  if$
}
```

Comment: The question is how I can implement this in the Biblatex environment.